# What recent evidence do we have for higher dimensions?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, spacetime-dimensions

I realize this question may have been asked some time ago, so do we have any up-to-date data for dimensions other than those of space/time?
Also, what do scientists mean by higher dimensions?

Comment: Please note that if you think the answers to the duplicate are outdated, the intended procedure is to offer a bounty with the "current answers are outdated" reason instead of duplicating the question.

Comment: thank you for the information